# Can not install SignalR client nuget package for MonoDroid

Tags: xamarin.android, signalr

I was trying to install Nuget package for MonoDroid project (Visual Studio 2015):

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
```

And I got this error:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.3', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

Any idea to sort this out?